# Auth-kit example is not working

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/auth-kit/example

After running yarn install and yarn start, I get a lot of missing dependencies.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please be more specific about what dependencies are missing?

The most common cause is a [Webpack 5 Polyfill issue](https://web3auth.io/docs/troubleshooting/webpack-issues) with Web3Auth, our AuthKit provider.

It usually results in errors like this: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto'`

This can be solved by following [these steps](https://docs.safe.global/learn/safe-core/safe-core-account-abstraction-sdk/auth-kit#install-dependencies) or looking at [this commit](https://github.com/5afe/safe-space/pull/12/commits/85ccd22b8528d7eacd013a8e3f5bb0093c85b081).

Summary:

1. Add missing dependences:

```bash
yarn add --dev react-app-rewired crypto-browserify \
stream-browserify assert stream-http https-browserify \
os-browserify browserify-zlib url buffer process
```

2. Use `react-app-rewired` and create a `config-overrides.js`

Comment: I've seen that the problem was that the instructions were outdated. With the new updated instruction, it works with no problem. I was missing the "yarn install" in the root folder, that was not said.